# to access username field using LoginHistory Object

Tags: soql, rest-api, relationships

I am trying to access Username field (which is present in User Object) Using LoginHistory Object as follow:

```
SELECT+Username+FROM+LoginHistory
```

but is shows below error:

> [{"message":"\nSELECT Username FROM LoginHistory\n       ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:8\nNo such column 'Username' on entity 'LoginHistory'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]**

also tried nested SOQL Query as :

```
SELECT+CountryIso,(SELECT+Username+FROM+User)+FROM+LoginHistory+limit+10
```

then also getting error.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 4):

As the error message suggests, there is no such column with API name as `Username` on `LoginHistory` object (Documentation for LoginHistory at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm) link). Although `Username` is a field on `User` object but that field cannot be queried from `LoginHistory` object using relationship query.

As mentioned, `Username` and all the fields related to `User` cannot be queried from the `LoginHistory` object, there is an idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DpuLAAS) for this specific requirement which you can up vote if you wish to and use the workaround mentioned at that link.

Excerpt from the above mentioned link (Workaround)

> As a workaround you can run a "User" report and add all the fields
>   from User object that you may want to include(make sure you add Login
>   Date/Time field).

**Note:**

- Regarding querying the related fields, you need to use the
  relationship queries for which you can refer
  [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql)
  link.
- As `User` object is not a child of `LoginHistory`, you cannot query
  on User using inner query of `LoginHistory`
- You cannot access parent's field directly in your SOQL query, you will have to use the relationship query eg : `Select Id, Account.Name FROM Contact`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make-do with two separate queries. There's equally no way to reverse it because the related list doesn't have name either.

Comment: can you please explain it with an example.